# Как реализовать подтверждение удаления записи из БД?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть готовый, рабочий код, который удаляет запись из БД:

```
if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
$id = ($_GET['delete']);
$query = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = $id";
mysqli_query($connect, $query);
}

<a href="?delete=<?=$post['id']?>" style="float: right;margin-left: 20px;"> 
<img src="../../images/delete.png" title="Удалить запись"></a>
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку с удалением записи всплывало окно на Bootstrap, которое спрашивает:

"Вы точно хотите удалить данную запись?", и предлагает два варианта:

- Кнопка "Да", которая при нажатии закрывает форму, а также удаляет запись
- Кнопка "Нет", которая просто закрывает форму

Вопрос, как это можно реализовать?

Вроде можно с помощью JS, но я в нём не особо разбираюсь пока что...

Заранее спасибо, всем добра! :)

Answer (score 0):

Логика может быть такой: на кнопку "Удалить" Вы вешаете просто открытие модального окна. На кнопку "Нет" вешаете закрытие модального окна. А вот на кнопку "Да" уже вешаете исполнение запроса в БД.

Comment: Всплывающее окно с вариантами ответов я реализовал, вот теперь вопрос, как правильно прикрутить к кнопке Да удаление записи из БД?

Comment: @heyone, и в чём проблема? Вы же говорите, что Ваш код рабочий. Сейчас он (как я понимаю) запускается по нажатию на картинку "удалить запись". А нужно запускать его по нажатию на кнопку "Да".

Comment: Нет. При нажатии на картинку должна всплывать форма с вариантами кнопок ответа, да или нет (это я реализовал), при нажатии на кнопку ДА форма должна удаляться запись из БД.

Comment: Странно, при выводе всплывающего окна перестало передаваться GET-значение..

Comment: `<a href="?delete=<?=$post['id']?>" style="float: right;margin-left: 20px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><img src="../../images/delete.png" title="Удалить запись"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

> Вроде можно с помощью JS, но я в нём не особо разбираюсь пока что...

На чистом JS это можно легко сделать через `confirm`.

```html
<a href="http://moi_url_address.ru/" target="_blank" onclick="test(event)">Удалить</a>
<script>
function test(e) {
   if(confirm('Удалить?')){
   return true;
   }else{
   e.preventDefault();
   }
};
</script>
```

Выведет стандартное окно браузера с двумя кнопками "Ok" и "Отмена".

Comment: мне нужно именно через всплывающее окно бутстрап. Я реализовал вывод окна, вот только почему то GET-значение не передаётся при нажатии на картинку удаления...

Comment: `<a href="?delete=<?=$post['id']?>" style="float: right;margin-left: 20px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><img src="../../images/delete.png" title="Удалить запись"></a>`

Comment: @heyone, если Вам нужно именно Bootstrap окно, замените вызов `confirm` на него. Принцип тот же, просто Bootstrap другой вариант реализации.

Comment: а как  делается замена правильно?
вот у меня вызов всплывающег окна:
`data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"`
Как его прикрутить?